# C# like events in Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript

How can I create a new event/ like in c# in javascript?

```
private event EventHandler asdCompleted;

private void SetEventHandlers()
{
    this.asdCompleted += asd_completed;
}

private void asd_completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

and fire the event anywhere like in c#:

```
this.asdCompleted(this, null);
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FGuide%2FDOM%2FEvents%2FCreating_and_triggering_events

Comment: take a look at my answer to this similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15963984/javascript-method-invocation-list/15964759#15964759

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*If you use jQuery*, then the answer is [jQuery Callbacks](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Callbacks/)

Answer (score 6):

you can define a simple delegate list, like the one used internally by .NET, as follows

```
function createEvent() {
    var invokeList = [];

    var event = function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < invokeList.length; i++) {
            invokeList[i].apply(arguments);
        }
    }

    event.add = function(value) {
        invokeList[invokeList.length] = value;
    }

    return event;
}

var foo = {
    myEvent: createEvent()
}

foo.myEvent.add(function() { console.log('in my event'); });
foo.myEvent.add(function() { console.log('also in my event'); });

foo.myEvent();
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
    document.asdCompleted = function(s){
            alert(s);
        }

    document.asdCompleted('test');  
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think not exactly, because this approach lacks the capability of adding serveral handlers to the same "event".